# Android VideoView and NavigationBar

Tags: android, android-videoview, navigationbar

I have **fullscreen activity and video view in my application**.

`NavigationBar` **hides automaticaly in 5 seconds**, when i don't touch a screen.

I've tried to add `onSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` to `videoview`, and tried `setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE)`, and i had no positive results.

What I need to do to prevent hiding `navigationbar`?

Answer (score -1):

you can simply add like this.

```
public class mediaController extends MediaController {
    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }
}
```

Comment: NavigationBar is not a MediaController. It's the bar with back and home buttons.